# send same values to another variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have to form pages and I am trying to send same values to another variable (linkmobile) if user agent is mobile. Could you please tell me what is the best way with minimal coding?

```
  var link = "reservation.html?";
  var linkmobile = "reservation-mobile.html?";

  link += "checkinYear="+ checkinYear;
  link += "&checkinDay="+ checkinDay;
  link += "&checkinMonth="+ checkinMonth;

  if(/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|OperaMini/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
    window.location.href = link-mobile;
  }
  else
    window.location.href = link;

}
```

Comment: you have a typo in your code. your variable first is called `linkmobile` and then `link-mobile`. plus you don't tell us what is not working with the code you show us.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
    var link = "reservation.html?";  

    if(/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|OperaMini/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
        link = "reservation-mobile.html?";
    }

    link += "checkinYear="+ checkinYear;
    link += "&checkinDay="+ checkinDay;
    link += "&checkinMonth="+ checkinMonth;

    window.location.href = link;
}
```